# Grammar of relative clause

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I have a question to rewrite the sentence:

My mother bought an interesting book last summer

-> The book which my mother gave me last summer **is interesting** (1)

-> The book which my mother gave me last summer **was interesting** (2)

Which one is correct? Can you explain why you choose that answer? Thank you

Comment: I think its "was"

Answer (score 1):

They both are.
The difference is in how the writer (the "me") currently experiences that gift:

> 1. The book which my mother gave me last summer is interesting

This means that the book is currently (that is, at the moment of writing) interesting to the writer.

> 2. The book which my mother gave me last summer was interesting

This means the writer lost their interest in the book, or that the book's contents are no longer relevant.